# Optimization of a Convex Function involving Standard Normal CDF and PDF

Tags: self-study, optimization

Could someone provide closed form solutions, if any, and steps to get there for the following optimization problem? Please note this function has been shown to be a convex function and hence a minimum and unique solution exists for this optimization.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{\left\{ x\right\} }{\min}\left\{ \left[\theta x^{2}+\sigma\frac{\phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}\right]+\left[\theta\left(W-x\right)^{2}+\frac{\phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}\right]\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Here, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Also, }W\geq x,\; x\geq 0,\;\theta>0,\:\sigma^{2}\text{ is the variance of a Normal Distribution.}
\end{eqnarray*}

FOC of this function  seems to give below, which we can see is zero at $x=W/2$. With $\sigma >0 $ Am I missing something?
\begin{eqnarray*}
4x-2W-\frac{\theta x\phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma\Phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}-\frac{1}{\sigma}\left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}\right]^{2}+\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)\phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma\Phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}+\frac{1}{\sigma}\left[\frac{\phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}\right]^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

How would this change, if the function (convex again) were as follows?

\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{\left\{ x\right\} }{\min}\left\{ \left[\theta x^{2}+\frac{\sigma x\phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}\right]+\left[\theta\left(W-x\right)^{2}+\frac{\sigma\left(W-x\right)\phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}\right]\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I'm not sure an easy closed form exists; you can find the derivatives in closed form, but setting them equal to 0 gives a transcendental equation that neither I nor Mathematica makes any headway on. Note also (pedantically) that a unique solution requires the function be *strictly* convex, though that is true here.

Comment: Thanks @Dougal, Would numerically solutions then be the only way to solve this? Could you please point me to some resources that you think might be relevant?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you interested in this problem? I have an interest in stochastic optimization and am wondering what the application would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @Dougal that there is no general closed-form solution.  However, for the special case of $\sigma=1$ there is.  Using Mathematica (v 10.1) define the following functions:

```
\[CapitalPhi][z_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z]
\[Phi][z_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z]
f[x_, \[Theta]_, \[Sigma]_, 
  w_] := \[Theta] x^2 + \[Theta] (w - 
      x)^2 + \[Sigma] \[Phi][\[Theta] x/\[Sigma]]/\[CapitalPhi][\
\[Theta] x/\[Sigma]] + \[Phi][\[Theta] (w - 
        x)/\[Sigma]]/\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta] (w - x)/\[Sigma]]
```

So f is your function of interest.  Differentiate it with respect to x:

```
g = D[f[x, \[Theta], \[Sigma], w], x]
```

If we set $x = w/2$ for that derivative we get

[image: derivative]

We see that when $\sigma=1$, the derivative is zero for all values of $\theta$.  There might be other special cases.

**Addition:**  Just another observation:  If $w$ and $\theta$ are kept fixed and $\sigma\to\infty$, then the result is $x = w/2 + 1/(2\pi)$.  If $w$ and $\sigma$ are kept fixed and $\theta\to\infty$, then $x = w/2$.  So it seems that $w/2 \le x \le w/2+1/(2\pi)$ for any values of $\theta$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: That's a nice observation, Jim. The value $w/2$ would serve well as the start of a few Newton-Raphson iterations in the general case.

Comment: Thanks all. Any thoughts on how this would change if the function were: (reflection in question now)\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{\left\{ x\right\} }{\min}\left\{ \left[\theta x^{2}+\frac{\sigma x\phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta x}{\sigma}\right)}\right]+\left[\theta\left(W-x\right)^{2}+\frac{\sigma\left(W-x\right)\phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{\theta\left(W-x\right)}{\sigma}\right)}\right]\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*} Please let me know if this should be made a new question.

Comment: It looks like the minimum $x$ is again $w/2$ for all $\sigma>0$, $\theta>0$, and $w>0$.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Yes, given that the new function is convex, that's immediate from its symmetry about $W/2$. I've realized though that I'm not 100% sure the function is convex? I believe it, but haven't been (quickly) able to show it.

Comment: @JimBaldwin  Thanks for your suggestions. Please note, the original function (the first one) seems to have a solution by setting $x=w/2$ with the FOC condition, which I had to add to the question since it was too long. Please see above. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Dougal, Please see the proof of convexity here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158042/convexity-of-function-of-pdf-and-cdf-of-standard-normal-random-variable.     A similar proof applies for the ratio of the density and distribution functions.

Comment: "Would that be correct?"  If you're asking if the first equation in the question above has a solution  of $x=w/2$, the answer is "Yes, but only when $\sigma=1$ or when $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ or when $\theta\rightarrow\infty$."  If you're asking about the last equation, then "Yes".

Comment: @JimBaldwin I meant $x=w/2$ is a solution even for the first and not just when $\sigma$ and $\theta$ have special values and in the limit. I have posted the steps above (included in question now). I might be missing something. If you spot it, please let me know. I will look through again as well. Again, much appreciative of your suggestions.

Comment: Plot the function for any set of values of $\theta>0$, $\sigma\ne1$, and $w>0$ and you'll see that the function gets smaller than the value with $x=w/2$.  For example with $\theta=1.1$, $\sigma=3$, and $w=4$, the value of $x$ that minimizes the first function is (approximately) 2.0722 with a function value of 10.3754.  With $x=w/2=2$ the function value is a bit larger at 10.3873.  "which we can see is zero at $x=w/2$" is not true for this case.  Close but not exactly true.

Comment: Uh, the lower limit for $x$ is less than $w/2$ for some combinations of $\theta<1$ and $\sigma<1$.  I'll have to re-think the lower limit.  A specific example is $\theta=0.1$, $\sigma=0.72$, and $w=12$ with the $x$ that minimizes the first function being 5.96019 (which is lower than $12/2=6$.